# How to alert text after slide range?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to alert text after slide range [jquery] ?

my first question is in picture.

[image]

And my second question is , When checked checkbox it's will disable slide range,
but when user click slide range it's will alert. How to apply code for, If slide range disable  it's will not alert when click.

and this is my script code

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input id="display_value" type="text" value="0"> 
<br>
<div id="slide_data"  style=" width: 300px; float: left; margin-top: 7px;"></div> 
<br>                        
<br>
<label style=" font-family: lato; font-size: 13px; ">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_disable" id="checkbox_disable" style="cursor: pointer;" />Disable Slide Range
</label>


<script>
window.onload=function(){
$(function() { 
      $("#slide_data" ).slider({
         range: "min",
         value: 0,
         min: 0,
         max: 1000,
         slide: function( event, ui ) {      
                  $( "#display_value" ).val(ui.value);
                }
      });
  

      $( "#checkbox_disable" ).click(function(){
       if(this.checked)
         {  
           $( "#slide_data" ).slider( "option", "disabled", true ); 
           alert('checked');         
         } 
       else 
         {
           $( "#slide_data" ).slider( "option", "disabled", false );
           alert('not checked');
         } 
      });        
    });
}



// after user slide we will call function filters_web_hosting_package //
$(document).ready(function (){
        $("#slide_data").click(
            function () {
                alert("Slide");
                //filters_web_hosting_package();
            }            
        );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in jQuery's [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-stop):

```
stop: function( event, ui ) {}
```

Your case:

```
stop: function(event, ui) {
   alert("test")
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h1nuaufc/5/)

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to use the slide method in the slide object. you can use the stop method. it will fire after you have slided. This way you dont need the last function you created.

The display of the value can still be in the slide method* so add the stop method for the if statement

```js
window.onload=function(){
$(function() { 
      $("#slide_data" ).slider({
         range: "min",
         value: 0,
         min: 0,
         max: 1000,
         slide: function( event, ui ) {      
           $( "#display_value" ).val(ui.value);
         },
         stop: function( event, ui ) {      
          if(ui.value > 500)
             alert("test");
         }
      });
  

      $( "#checkbox_disable" ).click(function(){
       if(this.checked) {  
           $( "#slide_data" ).slider( "option", "disabled", true ); 
           alert('checked');         
         } else {
           $( "#slide_data" ).slider( "option", "disabled", false );
           alert('not checked');
         } 
      });        
    });
}
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input id="display_value" type="text" value="0"> 
<br>
<div id="slide_data"  style=" width: 300px; float: left; margin-top: 7px;"></div> 
<br>                        
<br>
<label style=" font-family: lato; font-size: 13px; ">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_disable" id="checkbox_disable" style="cursor: pointer;" />Disable Slide Range
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$("#slide_data").mouseup` instead of `$("#slide_data").click`.

Working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h1nuaufc/6/).